# WiFi (WLAN) Stick with adjustable transmit power

Tags: wifi, wlan

I am looking for a WiFi (WLAN) USB Stick with

- adjustable transmit power like with internal Intel WiFi chips:

[image: transmit power]

I am aiming for low transmit power. An RP-SMA connector is preferable too but not necessary.